# Are DB questions going to be migrated from SO?

Tags: discussion, questions, migration

Are DB questions going to be migrated from SO to this site? If so, how does that work? Do we have to ask for a specific question to be migrated or do they try to apply some logic based on tags?

Comment: It should when is not related to programming. Probably there are mores question to migrate on SF. Anyway, the migration should be organically, at least on beta phase.

Comment: @bigown Do you know how to request that a question is migrated? Or do you mean the question would just be asked again on this site?

Comment: Just flag it on SO and ask it to be migrated. The mods on SO can do the magic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think, that questions will be migrated, while this site is in beta.

Afterwards you can flag a question for moderator attention and ask for migration.

Comment: good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think we should go ahead and find questions that we want migrated and at the very least make a list of them all in one place.