# Migration of questions vs. marking duplicate / Is there a facility for marking questions as "Duplicate of SO question"?

Tags: discussion, migration

I know that there's a facility for requesting a question be migrated (as per [this other meta question](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9/are-db-questions-going-to-be-migrated-from-so)), but I know in SO itself, there's a feature for marking a question as a duplicate - does anyone know if you can mark a question as a duplicate *across* SE's?

e.g., [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/153/what-it-the-difference-between-an-inner-join-and-an-outer-join) dba.SE question is pretty clearly a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/sql-difference-between-inner-and-outer-join) SO question - would we migrate the SO question, or just somehow mark this as a duplicate?

Comment: You cannot mark a question as duplicate across SE2.0 sites AFAIK. I don't know that that's necessary, as it can be migrated (gives traceability) and then it can be closed on the other site as duplicate (gives responsibility to the right people to decide). That shoul dbe sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

As a new site under construction I would not spend too much time in finding ways how to move questions to other sites.

1. For the site to live, we need a reasonable number of questions
2. The search box on this site doesn't search its neighbor sites. Answers which contain a link to the other site are very helpful

Comment: Disagree with #1 - for the site to live, we need a number of reasonable (on-topic) questions.